# How does sql server decides which transaction is first and which one is the last if both happen at the same time

Tags: sql-server-2008

I just have a basic question about transaction -
If two transactions from different sessions start exactly at the same time, one transaction has to wait till the other finishes. This is one of the ACID properties. Now my question is how will the system decide which transaction is the first one and which one has to wait as both transactions happen at exatly same time.

Comment: I don't think anyone other than the SQL Server team at Microsoft can give you a definite answer. But the real question is: why is it important to know? If one transaction blocks the other, I will focus on solving the blocking, not which one SQL Server decides to block.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Right, its not possible to determine that since its SQL Server Internal. As we see when there are two processes accessing same table, once process is declared as dead lock victim while other executes. So choosing a process as dead lock victim is completely taken care by SQL Server. I also believe it might consider the milli seconds or micro seconds difference between the two processes and set the priority.

Hope this helps!